# Simple C++ Thread Program Can't Be Compiled

Tags: compiling, c++, g++

The following is my 1st multi-threaded program. But while it was compiled, there is a linking error. The part of the error message:

```
std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&):
test.cpp (.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFviEJRiEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFviEJRiEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x33): undefined reference pthread_create
collect2: error ld return 1
```

---

```
#include<thread>

void f(int i) {}

int main() {
        std::thread t(f, 1);
        t.join();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it compiled just fine, but fails to link. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You need to compile with `-pthread` as a compile option.

I got your code to compile with this (though I added the `-Wall` function to give me all warning notices):

```
g++ -pthread -out foo.exe foo.cpp
```

(where `foo.cpp` was the input filename I used containing your code)

Answer (score 1):

Even if your program uses c++11's threading feature, you need to specify '-pthread' to successfully compile your program.

---

Please read below thread for more info
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=763369

Comment: ... just saw this answer, how's it any different than my answer which says the same thing?  (This answer was posted over a year AFTER my own answer.)

Comment: Agreed, it is same as yours. Just wanted to stress on "Even if your program uses C++11..", cuz my understanding was, "If I use C++11 standard then I do not need to supply any more options to compile because threads are supported by C++11" but clearly that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had  fixed the same Issue (undefined reference to Pthread_create)
So the issue is not your Code but the argument which be have missed while generating object file in G++ compiler

```c
void threadFun()
{
    cout<<"\n"<<"   "<<"INSIDE THREAD"<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(threadFun);
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the issue:

[image]

This is how I fixed it:

[image]

Comment: Basically the same as the other two answers?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this example:

https://mockstacks.com/Cpp_Threading

#include
#include
#include

using namespace std;

// The function we want to execute on the new thread.
void task1(string msg)
{
cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{
// Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
thread t1(task1, "Hello");

// Do other things...

// Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
t1.join();
}